# Page updates while processing

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I have a PHP script that can take a few minutes to be done. It's some search engine which executes a bunch of regex commands and retrieve the results to the user.

I start by displaying a "loading page" which does an AJAX call to the big processing method in my controller (let's call it 'P'). This method then returns a partial view and I just replace my "loading page" content with that partial view. It works fine.

Now what I would like to do is give the user some information about the process (and later on, some control over it), like how many results the script has already found. To achieve that, I do another AJAX call every 5 seconds which is supposed to retrieve the current number of results and display it in a simple html element. This call uses a method 'R' in the same controller as method 'P'.

Now the problem I have is that I'm not able to retrieve the correct current number of results. I tried 2 things :

- Session variable ('file' driver) : in 'P' I first set a session variable 'v' to 0 and then update 'v' every time a new result is found. 'R' simply returns `response()->json(session('v'))`
- Controller variable : same principle as above but I use a variable declared at the top of my controller.

The AJAX call to 'P' works in both cases, but everytime and in both cases it returns 0. If I send back 'v' at the end of the 'P' script, it has the correct value.

So to me it looks like 'R' can't access the actual current value of 'v', it only access some 'cached' version of it.

Does anyone have an idea about how I'm going to be able to achieve what I'd like to do? Is there another "cleaner" approach and/or what is wrong with mine?

Thank you, have a nice day!

__

Some pseudo-code to hopefully make it a bit more precise.

SearchController.php

```
function P() {
    $i = 0;
    session(['count' => $i]); // set session variable
    $results = sqlQuery(); // get rows from DB

    foreach ($results as $result) {

        if (regexFunction($result))
            $i++

        session(['count' => $i]); // update session variable

    }

    return response()->json('a bunch of stuff');
}

function R() {
    return response()->json(session('count')); // always returns 0
}
```

Comment: Are you using innoDB as the engine in your DB?

Comment: If you want to show the results count to user, you can simply count the return rows and me it a part of your return parameter from controller.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL which has its own storage engine if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks Anand, but I don't really see what you mean. What I would like to do is to display the number of results while the script is still processing. You can think of it as some sort of progress bar : every x seconds until the script is done, I want the user to know how many results already have been found.

Comment: In my opinion, you should return found result along with the count of total results found till now. You can hold total results found in every ajax request and send it back with url which then your controller again count the total current result plus result previously found and again send the consolidated number as return with ajax. The return object from controller should hold the result as well as current count

Comment: I don't want to send the actual results until the script is completely done processing.
What I can't seem to be able to do is to return the updated count.
My big processing script is updating either a controller variable or a session variable with the current count, and my second script (which is called every 5 seconds via AJAX) is supposed to simply return this current count but it just returns 0 (or whatever value I initialized it with). 
That is my problem, how can my 'every 5 seconds' script access the value updated by me 'big processing script'?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach here.
Read a bit more about flushing content here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php and then use it.

Long story short in order to display the numbers of row processed with flushing you could just make a loop result and flush from time to time or at an exact number or rows, the need for the 5 seconds AJAX is gone. Small untested example :

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach($result as $key => $val) {
     //do your processing here
     if ($cnt % 100 == 0) {
          //here echo smth for flushing, you can echo some javascript, tough not nice
          echo "<script>showProcess({$cnt});</script>";
          ob_flush();
     }
}
// now render the proccessed full result
```

And in the showProcess javascript function make what you want... some jquery replace in a text or some graphical stuff...

Hopefully u are not using fast_cgi, beacause in order to activate output buffering you need to disable some important features.

Comment: If I finally manage to make flush work (see answer below), I'll then have a problem if I want the user to be able to interrupt the process (AJAX call needed there to update some sort of variable that makes the big process stop). I may need a solution with AJAX calls anyway, if you can point me in the right direction regarding that part.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I am telling crap, but when the process starts maybe you can find the pid of the process, store it in a text file for each user or smth then make an ajax call that reads the pid from that file and kills the thread abruptly... ? Tough not nice and security issues can rise there...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have hit a wall with PHP limitations. PHP doesn't multithread, well. To achieve the level of interaction you are probably required to edit the session files directly, the path of which can be found in your session.save_path global through php_info(), and you can edit this path with [session_save_path(String)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php%20%22session_save_path(String)). Though this isn't recommended usage, do so at your own risk.

Alternatively use a JSON TXT file stored somewhere on your computer/server, identifying them in a similar manner to the session files.

You should store the current progress of the query to a file and also if the transaction has been interrupted by the user. a check should be performed on the status of the interrupt bit/boolean before continuing to iterate over the result set.

The issue arises when you consider concurrency, what if the boolean is edited just slightly before, or at the same time, as the count array? Perhaps you just keep updating the file with interrupts until the other script gets the message. This however is not an elegant solution.

Nor does this solution allow for concurrent queries being run by the same user. to counter this an additional check should be performed on the session file to determine if something is already running. An error should be flagged to notify the user.

Given the option, I would personally, rewrite the code in either JSP or ASP.NET

All in all this is a lot of work for an unreliable feature.